# I have some mesquite smoked brisket and would like to minimize the smoke flavor

Tags: flavor, smoking

I have some mesquite smoked beef brisket that is pretty smokey. Is there anything I can do to neutralize that strong flavor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Smoke flavor is challenging to work with, but I would think an appropriate barbecue sauce would fit the bill.  I wouldn't get anything too salty as I suspect that would worsen the perceived smokiness; but not too sweet because that will just clash with it.

I think a vinegar sauce would be probably best; acidity and bite would help cut through that smokiness.  A mustard sauce also could be a good fit for a similar reason.  (See the [Serious Eats guide](http://www.seriouseats.com/2011/05/barbecue-sauce-regional-styles-mustard-vinegar-tomato-white-sauce.html) to barbecue sauces for more details.)